# Rails render html into a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Is it possible to have rails render html into a hash instead of to the client?

Something like this:

```
@obj = {
 "foo" => Bar.find(1)
 "html" => (render :partial => "yatzhee")
}
render :json => @obj.to_json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render_to_string` takes all the same arguments as `render` but returns a string. You can then put that in a hash or do anything you want with that.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw anything like that.

If you want to render json, you should really take a look at [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). It's a joy to work with and it's the 'rails way' (~ it's merely built-in).

It allows you to render partials, for instance:

```
json.partial! "api/comments/comments", @message.comments
```